# event.target in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table and I want to : for each click on item in table, this item will be added to another table. This is my code:

```
$("#listResult table td").click(function(e){
    $("#addGroupMemberOfAdd").click(function(){
        alert("Add to List Member");
        $("#listMember table").append(
            '<tr><td style="padding-left: 5px;">'+$(e.target).attr('rel')+'</td></tr>');
        return false;
    })
    return false;
})
```

But that encounted a problem: if one table has 3 items, I click on item1, item1 is added to the other table, but when I click on item2, item1 is added to the other table again and item2 is added to this table. How to fix it????

Comment: Could you arrange a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: Why do you nest the click handlers? When you click on an item, all you do is attach a click handler to another item.

Comment: @Ronald i was going to ask the same thing. I don't understand the double nested handlers. As Rikudo mentioned can you add this code to jsfiddle and explain what exactly you want to do. Like do you want to be able to move the table item from table1 to table2 and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: when the second event fires, the event object (and thus it's target) may have changed.

(The way I read the code: when a td is clicked, a second click (e.g. on a OK button) moves it's content. Or does this second event fire immediately?)

I would suggest a different solution: The first click sets a variable to indicate the "active" td, the second click accesses this variable to see which td to move/add. In this way, you would avoid these anonymous functions (closures) generated on each click of td.